# Magento 2 Matrix rate Checkout Issue (Carrier with such method not found:matrixrate_5334)

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, magento2

I've searched everywhere to find solution without any results for now. We are facing issue with shipping methods when customer put payment and try to process order we hav an error "Carrier with such method not found:matrixrate_5334" and shipping method dissapear, cart need to be removed and created once again to see those shipping methods.

Php 7.0
Magento version 2.2.1 
Webshopp Matrixrates latest version
https://docs.shipperhq.com/troubleshooting-matrixrates/

Can anybody help?

[Pop up issue on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTr7.png)

Answer (score -1):

I noticed this error occurred due to the checkout session quote `$this->getShippingMethod()` not correctly set / null while calculating the shipping rates.

```
magento/codepool/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php
public function requestShippingRates(AbstractItem $item = null)
Line 1080: if ($this->getShippingMethod() == $rate->getCode()) {
```

Error:

```
{"message":"Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2","parameters":["matrixrate","matrixrate_2"]}
```

Solution:

I could resolve it by overriding the `\WebShopApps\MatrixRate\Model\Carrier\Matrixrate` `collectRates()` method and set the shipping method in checkout quote shipping address.

```
// set quote shipping method
$shippingMethod = $method->getCarrier().'_'.$method->getMethod();
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
```

============================================

```
Vendor/MatrixRate/etc/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="WebShopApps\MatrixRate\Model\Carrier\Matrixrate" type="Vendor\MatrixRate\Model\Carrier\Matrixrate"/>
</config>
```

Override `Vendor\MatrixRate\Model\Carrier\Matrixrate.php`

Inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession` to `__construct`

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
            }
        }

        // Free shipping by qty
        $freeQty = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            $freePackageValue = 0;
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                            $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                    $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                    $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
                }
            }
            $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
            $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
        }

        if (!$request->getConditionMRName()) {
            $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
            $request->setConditionMRName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->defaultConditionName);
        }

        // Package weight and qty free shipping
        $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
        $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

        $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();
        $zipRange = $this->getConfigData('zip_range');
        $rateArray = $this->getRate($request, $zipRange);

        $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

        $foundRates = false;

        foreach ($rateArray as $rate) {
            if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
                /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
                $method = $this->resultMethodFactory->create();

                $method->setCarrier('matrixrate');
                $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

                $method->setMethod('matrixrate_' . $rate['pk']);
                $method->setMethodTitle(__($rate['shipping_method']));

                if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {
                    $shippingPrice = 0;
                } else {
                    $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
                }

                $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
                $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

                $result->append($method);
                $foundRates = true; // have found some valid rates

                // set quote shipping method
                $shippingMethod = $method->getCarrier().'_'.$method->getMethod();
                $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
            }
        }

        if (!$foundRates) {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error $error */
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                        'carrier' => $this->_code,
                        'carrier_title' => $this->getConfigData('title'),
                        'error_message' => $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'),
                    ],
                ]
            );
            $result->append($error);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

FYI - Possible M2 core issues:

- https://github.com/webshopapps/module-matrixrate/issues/36
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3789
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25147

Cheers!